# Write access from a Windows client via a ZFS SMB, to a file created on the host in OpenIndiana

Tags: windows, solaris, server-message-block, zfs, openindiana

I've got an OpenIndiana server running ZFS that is shared using a `nobody` user and group. I don't fully understand Solaris ACL permissions, but I do know Linux style permissions. The client is Windows 8 and the server is OpenIndiana is oi_148.

I'm failing to work out how to make write permission work correctly for the Windows client. It is able to make new files, but can not modify files created by the shell in OpenIndiana.

When a file (`"local file"`) is created locally as the user `nobody` in bash, and another file (`"smb file"`) created remotely via SMB (as `nobody` also), they are quite different in permissions:

```
# ls -V
-rw-r--r--   1 nobody   nobody         0 Dec  2 12:24 local file
                 owner@:rw-p--aARWcCos:-------:allow
                 group@:r-----a-R-c--s:-------:allow
              everyone@:r-----a-R-c--s:-------:allow

-rwx------+  1 nobody   nobody         0 Dec  2 12:24 smb file
            user:nobody:rwxpdDaARWcCos:-------:allow
       group:2147483648:rwxpdDaARWcCos:-------:allow
```

In bash, I'm able to write to `smb file`, but vice versa, the Windows client is not able to write to `local file`. This is confusing to me because it appears that it should allow the SMB client to write to `local file`, because `nobody` is the owner and it has a `w` in the ACL.

The `sharesmb` setting is is fairly boring, although I'm hoping there can something to set in here similar to a umask:

```
sharesmb name=shared,guestok=true
```

How can I make these two work together and have a symmetrical permission system, where both SMB and the local user produce the same permissions?

Is there some sort of ACL that can set at the root of the file system to allow all files to be created in a similar manner?

Comment: I think there is confusion on whether networking questions belong on ServerFault because its name (and I believe its original definition) doesn’t match its current scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few problems with my set up:

- The ACL created by the local user didn't have `d` and `D` flags set which means it can't be deleted/moved, although I still don't understand why the local user was able to delete it when SMB was not able to.
- The ACL's weren't set in a way so that ACL's would be inherited, i.e. the `fd` flags.
- ZFS `aclinherit` property should be set to `passthrough` instead of `restricted`.

e.g.:

```
# chmod A=owner@:rwxpdDaARWcCos:fd:allow /z/shared
# zfs set aclinherit=passthrough z/shared
```

After creating files from SMB and locally:

```
$ ls -V
total 2
-rwx------+  1 nobody   nobody         0 Dec  8 00:17 local
                 owner@:rwxpdDaARWcCos:------I:allow
-rwx------+  1 nobody   nobody         0 Dec  8 00:17 smb
                 owner@:rwxpdDaARWcCos:------I:allow
```

Note the `I` which shows that the ACL is inherited.

The ZFS settings are described in the [ZFS administration guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/819-5461/gbacb.html):

> **restricted** – For new objects, the write_owner and write_acl
>   permissions are removed when an ACL entry is inherited.
>
> **passthrough** – When property value is set to passthrough, files are
>   created with a mode determined by the inheritable ACEs. If no
>   inheritable ACEs exist that affect the mode, then the mode is set in
>   accordance to the requested mode from the application.

Now the SMB client is able to delete files created locally.